# Issue with using history in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I'm making an application that involves chats, and in each chat, a user that is a part of that chat can create a post. I'm using the MERN stack and redux, and I have a component called PostForm, which is where users can make posts. I also have an addPost action for redux. After someone adds a post to a chat, I want to redirect them to their profile using history. However it is not working for me for some reason. I have attached my PostForm file as well as my addPost action and my post.js reducer (which is the relevant reducer). If anyone can find the issue for why it isn't redirecting to the profile page, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

PostForm.js:

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { addPost } from '../../actions/chat';
    
    const PostForm = ({ addPost, match, history }) => {
      const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        title: '',
        text: ''
      });
    
      const {
        title,
        text
      } = formData;
    
      const onChange = e => setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    
      const onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        addPost(match.params.id, { title, text }, history);
        console.log(formData);
        setFormData({
          [title]: '',
          [text]: ''
        })
    
      }
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="post-form">
            <div className="post-form-header bg-primary">
              <h3>Create a Post</h3>
            </div>
            <form className="form my-1" onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}
            >
              <textarea
                name='title'
                cols="30"
                rows="2"
                placeholder="Create post title"
                value={title}
                onChange={e => onChange(e)}
              />
              <textarea
                cols="30"
                rows="5" placeholder="Create a post"
                name='text'
                value={text}
                onChange={e => onChange(e)}
              />
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-dark my-1" />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
    
    PostForm.propTypes = {
      addPost: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    }
    
    export default connect(null, { addPost })(PostForm);



chat.js actions file

import axios from 'axios';
import { setAlert } from './alert';
import {
  CREATE_SUCCESS,
  CREATE_FAIL,
  GET_PROFILE,
  PROFILE_ERROR,
  USER_LOADED,
  AUTH_ERROR,
  JOIN_SUCCESS,
  JOIN_FAIL,
  ADD_POST
} from './types';
import setAuthToken from '../utils/setAuthToken';

// Add post
export const addPost = (chatId, formData, history) => async dispatch => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }

  //const body = JSON.stringify({ title, text });

  try {
    const res = await axios.post(`/api/chats/${chatId}`, formData, config);
    dispatch({
      type: ADD_POST,
      payload: res.data
    });

    dispatch(setAlert('Post Created', 'success'));

    history.push('/profile');
  } catch (err) {
    const errors = err.response.data.errors;

    if (errors) {
      errors.forEach(error => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, 'danger')));
    }

    
  }
}
```

chat.js reducer

```
import {
  JOIN_SUCCESS,
  JOIN_FAIL,
  ADD_POST
} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {

  token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
  //isAuthenticated: null,
  isCompleted: null,
  loading: true,
  user: null,
  error: {}
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case JOIN_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        ...payload,
        isCompleted: true,
        loading: false
      };
    case JOIN_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: payload,
        loading: false
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

App.js

```
 import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar';
import Landing from './components/layout/Landing';
import Login from './components/auth/Login';
import Register from './components/auth/Register';
import Alert from './components/layout/Alert';
// Redux
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
import { loadUser } from './actions/auth';
import setAuthToken from './utils/setAuthToken';
import Profile from './components/profile/Profile';
import PrivateRoute from './components/routing/PrivateRoute';
import CreateChat from './components/chat-form/CreateChat';
import JoinChat from './components/chat-form/JoinChat';
import Chat from './components/profile/Chat';
import PostForm from './components/profile/PostForm';

import './App.css';

if (localStorage.token) {
  setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
}

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    store.dispatch(loadUser());
  }, []);

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <Fragment>
          <Navbar />
          <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
          <section className="container">
            <Alert />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
              <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path='/profile' component={Profile} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path='/create-chat' component={CreateChat} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path='/join-chat' component={JoinChat} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path='/chat/:id' component={Chat} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path='/post-form/:id' component={PostForm} />
            </Switch>
          </section>
        </Fragment>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  )
};

export default App;
```

Comment: What is rendering `PostForm`? Is it correctly receiving a `history` prop? What routing/navigation library is being used?

Comment: @DrewReese PostForm is rendered through a link. I'm relatively new to react, so while I'm not certain it is receiving history correctly, I'm pretty sure it is. In my app.js I use react-router-dom.

Comment: `Link`s don't render components, `Route`s do. Can you provide your routing component code?

Comment: I think that's my app.js file. If this isn't correct let me know.

Comment: One second, I'm trying to figure out how to add code to a comment.

Comment: It is likely *that* file, but if it isn't it'll be the one near the root with a `Router` and wrapped `Route` components. Please don't add code in comments, just update your question.

Comment: Ok I just added it to my code. Thanks for the tip about putting the code in my question, this is my first time using stack overflow and I'm getting used to how it works.

Comment: Nothing stands out as incorrect to me. Have you logged the `history` object each time it is passed/referenced to ensure it is piped all the way through to invocation? Have you any errors at all (i.e. undefined when invoking)?

Comment: did you installed thunk to pass the actions. I do not think your action fired. can you please add this into the action: console.log("post action is fired") to see if that action is fired

Comment: Thanks everyone for the suggestions. I was able to fix it by handling the state at a component level. I'm still trying to figure out why this works instead though.